# Fastest way to read Excel using Interop and save in DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, export

After searching in Internet and trying some codes i exported data from Excel to Datatable with Interop. The Problem is, it's very slow. Can someone give me a key how can i make it quicker with Interop, not OLEDB or anything else?

My code:

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(userSelectedFilePath2);
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet1 = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange1 = xlWorksheet1.UsedRange;

DataTable excelTb1 = new DataTable();

for (int j = 1; j <= xlRange1.Columns.Count; j++) // Header Names
{
    excelTb1.Columns.Add(xlRange1.Cells[1, j].Value2.ToString());
}

DataRow dataRow = null;

for (int row = 2; row < xlRange1.Rows.Count + 1; row++)
{
    dataRow = excelTb1.NewRow();

    for (int col = 1; col <= xlRange1.Columns.Count; col++)
    {
        dataRow[col - 1] = (xlRange1.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Value2;
    }
    excelTb1.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}

xlWorkbook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
dataGridView1.DataSource = excelTb1;
```

Comment: Why do you need to use *interop* instead of any other technique?

Comment: @SteveB: i tried wiht many other techniques, OLEDB and NPOI but got many problems. OLEDB read only 255chars and NPOI has to add dll file and update POI, which is a little complicated

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an answer to a question you didn't ask. Use [NPOI library](http://code.google.com/p/npoi/downloads/list).

- it will be faster
- you won't have problems with forgetting to close your resources
- Excel will not be required or used in the background

Here's the relevant code for that: [NPOI : How To Read File using NPOI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855813/npoi-how-to-read-file-using-npoi) . For `xlsx` formats, use `XSSFWorkbook` instead (it is available starting from version 2.0).

Comment: i tried with NPOI, but i'm not use to it. Which are better NPOI or EPPlus?

Comment: @UniLe I'm sorry, but I can't help you with that.

Comment: when i use NPOI, i got FileXmlOfficeException coz i want to read xlsx file instead of xls. So i changed to XSSF but now got problem that i have to update POI. It's complicated

Comment: don't know the exact schema, but xlsx are simply zip files with xml content inside. Maybe you can use the OpenXML SDK to get the xml content, and explore it?

Comment: @SteveB NPOI supports both `xlsx` and `xls` files.

Comment: so how can i read using NPOI xlsx file without Apache's POI? Apache's POI is a java lib so i need IKVM, it's complicated, isn't it?

Comment: @UniLe There are no "NPOI xlsx" files, only Excel xlsx files. It seems that you are using C#. In that case, you head to the link in my post, click on it, and download the library. It comes with binaries (`NPOI.dll`) and examples. NPOI is a .NET port of Apache POI which is a Java library. Sadly, you must make a minimal effort on your part. There's even an answer to your question here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855813/npoi-how-to-read-file-using-npoi

Comment: i tried it many times, but it gived me ERROR FileXmlOfficeException, use XSSF instead of SXXF. I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: @UniLe Then why don't you use `XSSFWorkbook`? It's available starting from NPOI 2.0 (http://code.google.com/p/npoi/downloads/list).

Comment: i tried the link you gave me 2.0 but still got the same error: `The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)` so i changed from HSSFWorkbook to XSSFWorkbook but my compiler didn't recognize it

Comment: @UniLe I don't have such problems when testing. Try on a separate project - I'm quite certain the error is on your side.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19466/discussion-between-ipavlic-and-uni-le)

Answer (score 0):

My First thoughts on this are that you are looping through the Excel sheet and converting values one-by-one int your array to populate your structure.

Try something more along the lines of (Forgive my VB, but i'm sure oyu'll understand what I'm recommending):

```
Dim SpreadsheetVals(,) as object
SpreadhseetVals = xlWorksheet1.UsedRange
```

Then do your looping through your array instead.

That should improve speed considerably.