# "Retrieving the COM class factory for component.... error: 80070005 Access is denied." (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis

I just created a simple application and hosted in **IIS6.0**. In code I'm just instantiating excel objects.

```
using excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;

namespace TestHosting
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            excel excelObj=new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        }
    }
}
```

Its giving me following error

```
 "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied." (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

System Configuration:

**Windows server 2008,enterprise edition with 64 bit.**
service pack 2

I tried with many possible solutions  found on internet,but none of them were worked for me.

Some solution I tried are below

**1) creating Desktop application under the path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile"
2)setting full permission/control for Microsfot.EXcelApplicaiton in DCOMCNFG
3)Killing all excel instances in Task Manager**

Please help me in this regard,this is just sample app but in my original app is mostly about read and writing data from/to excel.

Comment: what about aps.net authentication? is it enabled?

Comment: Do you have Excel installed on the server? The interop interfaces you're using are used to _automate_ Excel which requires that the Excel application is installed there. Each page request cycle will potentially launch a separate instance of excel.exe. I would strongly advise against doing this as part of a web application. Why do you want to do this? If you are wanting to generate Excel documents, there are _much_ better ways to do this such as OpenXML.

Comment: there  was problem with permissions. I fixed it..thanks everyone

Comment: @Ram Im facing the same issue. Can you explain which permissions you fixed?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have Office runtime installed on the server.
2. If you are using Windows Server 2008 then using office interops is a lenghty configuration and here are the steps.

Better is to move to Open XML or you can configure as below

- Install MS Office Pro Latest (I used 2010 Pro)
- Create User ExcelUser.  Assign WordUser with Admin Group
- Go to Computer -> Manage
- Add User with below options
- User Options Password Never Expires
- Password Cannot Be Change

Com+ Configuration

- Go to Control Panel - > Administrator -> Component Services -> DCOM Config
- Open Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Properties
- General -> Authentication Level : None
- Security -> Customize all 3 permissions to allow everyone
- Identity -> This User -> Use ExcelUser /password
- Launch the Excel App to make sure everything is fine

3.Change the security settings of Microsoft Excel Application in DCOM Config.

Controlpanel --> Administrative tools-->Component Services -->computers --> myComputer -->DCOM Config --> Microsoft Excel Application.

Right click to get properties dialog. Go to Security tab and customize permissions

See the posts here: [Error while creating Excel object](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6388275-b295-4e55-8c25-6d8788eac1ca/error-while-creating-excel-object) , [Excel manipulations in WCF using COM](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1d5f1c83-10a7-4322-80a9-0a4348c738c9/excel-manipulations-in-wcf-using-com)

Comment: This technique worked for me on Windows Server 2012 R2 with Word + Office 2010 installed

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I was trying to create excel so I was on setting **Controlpanel --> Administrative tools-->Component Services -->computers --> myComputer -->DCOM Config --> Microsoft Excel Application** but I had to configure **Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Properties** also. 
Can anyone tell me why is it?

Comment: There is no Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 under DCOM Config on Windows Server 2012 R2 with Office 365 Business installed

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was great

Comment: Thanks! It saved a lot for me

Comment: @bot You, sir, saved my week.

Comment: got it to work but wasted a day and learned to never use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ever again, I'm switching to a third party lib

Answer (score 43):

Sometimes, you create new application pool and cann't solve it via DCOMCNFG. Then there is another method to do:

Set the **Identity** (Model Name) of application pool to **LocalSystem**.

I don't know the root cause, but it solve my problem one time.

Comment: This allows the application to be run with higher privileges and in most cases will fix the issue easily. +1 for the answer on that one. However, remember that running an application pool under an account that has high-level user rights is a **serious security risk**. More info on this [on MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx). So, I would advise only changing the identity if you're comfortable with the risks and know what the impact could be.

Comment: i would have really committed suicide, if a genius (in form of you) wasn't born... salute you man... you saved me...

Comment: I tried every other solutions around including all of the DCOMCnfg -32, and have no luck until I apply this one.

Comment: This worked for me. For changing identity of application pool, Open the IIS Management Console (INETMGR.MSC).
Open the Application Pools node underneath the machine node. Select the application pool you want to change to run under **Local System** identity.
Right click the application pool and select Advanced Settings
Select the Identity list item and click the ellipsis (the button with the three dots).[msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

Comment: +1000 points - I was looking for 3 days now and it didn't made any sense - THANKS

Comment: Still the problem exists in my case . I'm really about to commit suicide

Comment: This worked for me in addition of     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965150/microsoft-office-excel-cannot-access-the-file-on-iis
=> Create the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop folder

Answer (score 12):

Too late to respond. But, if this helps someone who is still facing the issue. I got this fixed by:

→ Set site on dedicated pool instead of shared one.

→ Enable 32 bit application support.

→ Set identity of the application pool to LocalSystem.

Comment: Thank you. For me, in my local test environment, all I needed to do was step 3: Set identity of the application pool to LocalSystem.

Comment: To LocalSystem, then it essentially runs with kernel permissions. That is killing a musquito with a bazooka. Please don't do that and follow the DCOM suggestion above.

Answer (score 5):

1. give the read / write permission to the IIS user or group users
2. Start -> run -> inetmgr

   enable the ASP.NET authentication for your default website

3.
For 64-bit (x64), create this folder:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

For 32-bit (x86), create this folder:
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

The windows service, if running under the systemprofile, needs the Desktop folder. This folder was automatically created on XP and older Windows Server versions, but not for Vista and Windows 2008 Server.

Comment: thanks for reply,2 and 3 steps I tried, but regarding 1 step,where should I give permissions for IIS users or group users?

Comment: On Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit and Excel with Office 365 64-bit, I created the 64-bit folder and still had the issue. After 2 days of troubleshooting I tried creating the 32-bit folder as well and it immediately worked.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I ran these exact steps:
* Install Interop Assemblies: you can install from Microsoft's website https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508&tduid=(09cd06700e5e2553aa540650ec905f71)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-yuTjfb1FeDiXvvZxhh.R.Q)()  
 
* Check assemblies version: check the version of the assemblies on development and production machines. The assemblies will be in the GAC, in widows 7 this folder is %windir%\assembly. 
* Create a Desktop folder: the service uses the desktop folder under systemprofile so you will need to create this folder if not there, here is the location of the folder:
For 64 bit applications : C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
For 32 bit applications : C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop 
* Add DCOM user permissions:
 
---start the run window and type 'dcomcnfg'.
---Expand Component Services –> Computers –> My Computer –> DCOM Config.
---Look for Microsoft Excel Application. Right click on it and select properties, then select the Security tab.
---Select the Customize radio button under 'Launch and Activation Permissions' and 'Access Permission' and click the Edit button for both to add users as follows.
---------Click the Add button and users 'IIS_IUSRS' and 'NETWORK SERVICE' and give them full privileges.
---Go to the Identity tab and select "The interactive user" option.
---Click Apply and OK.

Answer (score 3):

solution that worked for me is to change user under which Application Pool is started (ApplicationPoolIdentity obviously has not enough rights to access COM object).

Good luck!

Comment: I figured out that this worked as well, but then I thought perhaps a better solution would be to set the permissions on the DCOM object(s) themselves, [kind of like this link](http://tanveeronline.blogspot.com/2012/05/component-with-clsid-xxx-failed-due-to.html)

Answer (score 3):

try to do the following:

1. Make sure Office interop assemblies are installed.
2. Check the version of the assemblies on development and production.
3. Create Desktop folder under systemprofile.
4. set the DCOM security explicitly for the service user.

you can find more details [**here**](http://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/error-office-interop-assemblies/)

Answer (score 2):

> I just created a simple application

What is the target processor of the application? I am guessing it is `x86` - so either set it to `x64` or `anycpu`.

I think the issue you are having is due to a 64bit process trying to access a 32bit dll.

Also, if you can't change the target processor you could try to enable 32-bit Applications from the Application Pools settings in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Excel installed on the server? The interop interfaces you're using are used to *automate* Excel which requires that the Excel application is installed there. Each page request cycle will potentially launch a separate instance of excel.exe. I would strongly advise against doing this as part of a web application.

Why do you want to do this? If you are wanting to generate Excel documents, there are *much* better ways to do this, including OpenXML as mentioned elsewhere on this thread. *Please do not run Excel on the server!*

Link to OpenXML SDK download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a permission problem.  I suggest running processMonitor to determine what permissions are needed.

Answer (score 1):

use [**NPOI**](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) to read and write excel..it's free and open source

for exapmle

```
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;

//.....

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HSSFWorkbook hssfwb;
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"c:\test.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        hssfwb= new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    }

    ISheet sheet = hssfwb.GetSheet("Arkusz1");
    for (int row = 0; row <= sheet.LastRowNum; row++)
    {
        if (sheet.GetRow(row) != null) //null is when the row only contains empty cells 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Row {0} = {1}", row, sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(0).StringCellValue));
        }
    }
}
```

see this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855813/npoi-how-to-read-file-using-npoi)

Answer (score 1):

Came across this issue two days back, spent whole complete two days, So I found that I need to give the access to IUSR user group at 
DCOMCNFG --> My Computer Properties --> Com Security --> Launch and Activation Permissions --> Edit defaults and give all rights to IUSR.

hope it will help someone....

Answer (score 0):

Use this

## create a user in admin group

## add this user details in web config like below

```
<system.web>
   <identity impersonate="true"
    userName="User Name"
    password="Password" />
    `enter code here`</system.web>
```

## restart the IIS and check again

-tony-

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to configure this on 64bit, you have to do your DCOMconfig configuration (see other answers above) in:

```
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64>mmc comexp.msc /32
```

according to [Setting Process-Wide Security Using DCOMCNFG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/setting-processwide-security-using-dcomcnfg).

After this, I was able to configure this for `IIS_IUSRS` without administrator privileges.