# Error E_ACCESSDENIED in C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel()

Tags: c#, excel, windows-services, office-interop, access-denied

I have created a **windows service** that repetitively updates the same **excel file**. While running the Windows Service, I am receiving the following **Error**:

> Error Message Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

This error is thrown at the following line of code:

```
ExcelApp =  new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

Is there a work-around for this ?

I followed the steps mentioned in the following [**SO link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785063/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-error-80070005-access-is-de) but that didn't helped me overcome these error. I tried solution from few other questions as well and none of them worked for me.

Comment: Office programs are woefully unfit to run in session 0.  Don't do it.  Use the openxml api instead.