# I need to fix this error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis

My application is running in asp.net(4.5) webform C# . In my application there is a need to create excel sheet.

```
// code to create excel
xlsWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\\" + filename, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlsWorkbook.Close(true, filename, null);
xlsApp.Quit();
xlsWorksheet = null;
xlsWorkbook = null;
xlsApp = null;
Process.Start(@"c:\"); // Open file after download
```

As you can see I am saving generated excel file inside C drive. This work perfectly while I'm running locally. But after publishing,this error is throwing

**

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)). 
ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user. 
To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace: 
[UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +119
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +247
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   e2aPortal.homeUserControl.CreateTopic.ExportToExcel() +112
   e2aPortal.homeUserControl.CreateTopic.btnDownloadExcel_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) +5
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9767618
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1738
```

**

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked file/folder permissions in production machine's IIS? Try using `LocalSystem` as suggested in similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785063/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-error-80070005-access-is-de.

Comment: The application pool runs under an account that cannot access everything on the server. This is for security reasons and for good reasons. If you want users to be able to access these files then you need to grant the application pool account access to the location of the files. If is intranet and you are using window auth, then use impersonation so you know who did what to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Well as the message says it's a permission issue. Your application runs as a Windows user on the machine it's installed on. Do you know what users it runs as? 
You can try one of the following:
(1) give permissions to that windows user to write on the root of the c: drive (or ideally a specific subfolder)
(2) run your application under another user that has higher privileges
(3) use a setting in your application config file, that specifies where the file should be created.
(4) write into the user's default folder (C:\Users\username), I think this is done by specifying a filename without putting the c:\ in front of it

```
xlsWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel dll is not a good idea for web applications.
You need to configuration DCOM settings,allow w3wp to access it ,and this may cause security problems.

I noticed your demand is to create excel file for downloading.
You can try NPOI [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)

This project is the .NET version of POI Java project at http://poi.apache.org/. POI is an open source project which can help you read/write xls, doc, ppt files. It has a wide application.