# FluentFTP not working in SSIS failed to load the FluentFTPDLL

Tags: ssis, ftp, fluentftp

Getting following error message while executing the package.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'FluentFTP, Version=19.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4af092b1d8df44f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Please help what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

SSIS Engine is not able to load corresponding DLL.
You have to deploy the DLL into Windows GAC of the SSIS Server - see [answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37682925).