# Trying to edit cell value of existing Excel file using NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I have written the following code to edit an Excel file using C# and NPOI library.  There are no errors, but after running the code if I open the file, the value of the cell is not edited.  What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace Project37
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string pathSource = @"C:\Users\mvmurthy\Downloads\VOExportTemplate.xlsx";

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite); 
            HSSFWorkbook templateWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs, true);
            HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet)templateWorkbook.GetSheet("ImportTemplate");
            HSSFRow dataRow = (HSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(4);

            dataRow.GetCell(1).SetCellValue("foo");

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            templateWorkbook.Write(ms);
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The main reason that you are not seeing the changes is because you are writing the workbook to a `MemoryStream` instead of writing back to the file.  What you should be doing is this:

1. using a `FileStream` in `Read` mode to read the spreadsheet file completely;
2. making the changes you want, then
3. using a `FileStream` in `Write` mode to write back to the file (or optionally write to a different file if you don't want to destroy the original -- this may be better for testing).

Also note it is good practice to use `using` statements when working with classes that implement `IDisposable` (all `Streams` do).  This will ensure that the file is closed and all resources used by the stream are cleaned up properly.

There is another problem I see in your code, and that is you are apparently trying to use an `HSSFWorkbook` with an `.xlsx` file.  That won't work.  `HSSFWorkbook` (and all `HSSF` classes) are for `.xls` files.  If you need to work with `.xlsx` files, then you should be using `XSSFWorkbook` and related `XSSF` classes instead.  Note that both flavors of classes implement common interfaces like `IWorkbook`, `ISheet`, `IRow`, etc. to help reduce code duplication should you need to support both types of files.  I recommend using them where possible.  But you may find you still need to downcast occasionally to access certain features that are not covered by the interfaces.

One other thing I should mention: if a particular row `x` contains no cells in the original workbook, then `GetRow(x)` will return null.  Similarly, `GetCell(y)` will return null if cell `y` is empty.  If you want to be able to set the value of the cell regardless, you will need to check for nulls and use `CreateRow(x)` and/or `CreateCell(y)` as appropriate to ensure each respective entity exists.

Here is the revised code:

```
string pathSource = @"C:\Users\mvmurthy\Downloads\VOExportTemplate.xlsx";

IWorkbook templateWorkbook;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    templateWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
}

string sheetName = "ImportTemplate";
ISheet sheet = templateWorkbook.GetSheet(sheetName) ?? templateWorkbook.CreateSheet(sheetName);
IRow dataRow = sheet.GetRow(4) ?? sheet.CreateRow(4);
ICell cell = dataRow.GetCell(1) ?? dataRow.CreateCell(1);
cell.SetCellValue("foo");

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    templateWorkbook.Write(fs);
}
```

Comment: The best example for showing how to write to a existing file by NPOI C# in the whole internet.

Comment: This is great but what if you don't know you need to modify cell 1 in row 4? How to iterate? Sorry C# is a 2nd language for me.

Comment: @usr-bin-drinking - If you are having trouble, you should [open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) explaining what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried, and where you are getting stuck.  You can include a [link back to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38992551/10263) to provide context.  That way more people will see it and you will have a better chance of getting an answer that helps you.  A comment is not a good place to ask new questions.