# Read Excel using NPOI

Tags: c#, xlsx, xls, npoi

I am trying to read excel[xls and xlsx] using NPOI,I am using following code, but it is giving 'Unable to Read entire header; 27 bytes Read; expected 512 bytes' while reading an 8KB xls file

```
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filepath);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filepath ?? ""));

    NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFWorkbook hssfwb = default(HSSFWorkbook);
    hssfwb = new NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFWorkbook(stream1);
    Sheet sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);
    DataTable dtinputExcel = new DataTable();
```

I have tried every possible code available on net for this error. Please guide me what's the errorless method to read and excel[xls/xlsx] of any size.

Comment: check if your file is not open in an oter program, You could be reading the lock instead of the file.

Comment: I have closed excel process through coding before reading excel/calling above code, but still it gives the error.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855813/npoi-how-to-read-file-using-npoi

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the constructor of `HSSFWorkbook` is expecting a stream containing the *contents* of the spreadsheet file, while you are passing it a `MemoryStream` containing the *name* of the file.  You should be using a [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) to read the file and passing that stream to the `HSSFWorkbook` constructor.

Try it like this:

```
IWorkbook hssfwb;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
}

ISheet sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);
```