# How to Update content from Excel to MySql Database using C#.Net

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I need to update the given Excel into MySql database using C# and .Net Framework

Can anyone help me in providing the reference links,so that i can learn and implement the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't question for stack overflow, but to get you started (and in future to return to  SO and ask specific question with code sample :))

For reading and writing Excel files, it would be the easiest to use [NPOI](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=npoi), .net port of Apache POI.

Then, google a bit and you can find a lot of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855813/how-to-read-file-using-npoi) like [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1048898/Read-Excel-using-NPOI) or [maybe this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813187/Csharp-Read-and-Write-Excel-xls-and-xlsx-Files-Con)

To access MySQl you have everything you need in .NET framework or you can use [MySQL Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html). Of course, there are a lot of [samples](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL), especially on [stack owerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618015/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database)