# c#: Accessing cells in excel worksheet throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, excel

So I've been trying to write a console application (.Net Core) which reads data from an Excel file but I'm kinda stuck.

I've been trying to get this code sample to work: https://www.csharp-console-examples.com/general/reading-excel-file-in-c-console-application/

I needed to use `(Range)cell` explicitly because Visual Studio threw errors when the sample code tried to access the cell directly.

When trying to load the worksheet and the used range `m_ObjectToDataMap = null` for both worksheet and range. Accessing the rows with excelRange.Rows fails due to System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Create COM Objects.
    Application excelApp = new Application();

    if (excelApp == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Excel is not installed!!");
        return;
    }

    Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\test.xlsx");
    _Worksheet excelSheet = (_Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets[1];
    Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

    foreach (Range row in excelRange.Rows)  // Here is the NullReference Error
    {
        // create new line
        Console.Write("\r\n");
        foreach (Range col in excelRange.Columns)
        {
            Range cell = (Range)excelRange.Cells[row, col];
            // write the console
            if (excelRange.Cells[row, col] != null && cell.Value2 != null)
                Console.Write(cell.Value2.ToString() + "\t");
        }
    }
    //after reading, relaase the excel project
    excelApp.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I tried a lot of different code, looping through all sheets or calling the sheet by its name but it always ends with worksheet and range being loaded incorrectly and the NullReferenceException.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you probably have merged cells... you also need to free worksheets, ranges and workbooks

Comment: For testing purposes i just wrote "test" into the first 6 cells (3 in row 1 and 3 in row 2) so the exel file should be fine

Comment: I know what a NullReference is but i cant find how i should load the worksheet (or the range) correctly

Comment: Why are you making a new "range" of the a single cell every loop, just read the cell

Comment: well i never came that far because excel.Range.Rows and excel.Range.Columns throws the NullReferenceException. The sample code was without the explicit (Range) conversion but visual studio threw errors so i had to do it explicitly like this

Comment: dont use rows.count, use excelRange.GetLength(0).. and then pick up the value with excelRange.cells[i,j].Value2

Comment: CS1061 'Range' does not contain a definition for 'GetLength' and no accessible extension method 'GetLength' accepting a first argument of type 'Range' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value2' and no accessible extension method 'Value2' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
--> this is why i used Range cell instead of direct access

Answer (score 0):

I think the code reference you were using was a console app in .NET Framework. I used the code from [here](https://www.csharp-console-examples.com/general/reading-excel-file-in-c-console-application/) that you referenced and put it in a .NET Framework console application and it works perfectly. I put the same code in a .NET Core console application and it does not work. So you might need to change to .NET Framework or you can use another excel library. I use NPOI which you can follow an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855813/how-to-read-file-using-npoi) or do some more googling to find other examples. There is also probably more libraries out there like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started) that work in .NET Core for parsing excel but I have not used or looked into any others.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code after extensive testing and it seems to work in .NET Framework as well as .NET Core:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

string svalue = getStrFromValue((worksheet.Cells[iRow, j] as Excel.Range).Value

string getStrFromValue(dynamic value)
{
    if (value != null)
        return (string)(value.ToString()).Trim();
    else
        return "";
}
```

Please note that there are two values on an Excel.Range-Object: Value and Value2. With a Date-Value 'Value' returns a Date-String while 'Value2' returns a number. Excel.Interop is really cool but very buggy and not well documented at the same time..